# How to grab specific part of url in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, url

My Url looks like : www.ccadmin/admin.jsp?id=Aetna834

How to grab Aetna834

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Comment: Is there any difference in AngularJS

Comment: No, it's plain *javascript*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in plain JS, or you can use the `$location` service, which is a little easier IMO. "Aetna834" would be found using:

`$location.search().id`